# HTML table row of cells in cell

Tags: html, html-table

I'm having trouble getting cells next to each other.
What I'm trying to get are 3 rows of cells next to each other but just can't get it working.
What I'm trying to do:

```html
<table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <tr>
                    <td>15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>22</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline;">
                <tr>
                    <td>15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>22</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline;">
                <tr>
                    <td>15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>22</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

which does something like this:

```
Region  1   2   3
15
22

15
22

15
22
```

and I need the numbers to be next to each other but they end up being on top of each other instead and just can't figure it out. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok we see what it does. But how exactly should the result look like?

Comment: Your html is broken, it's missing ending table-tag and you have tr-tags inside td-tags, that is not valid. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). If you want the numbers to be on the same line, you need to create multiple td-elements inside a row (tr).

Comment: Inside the first row add one new table with three columns.